# How to add flag to active record object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have an object like this

```
@contacts = Contact.first(5)
```

Contact table has 4 column, name, id, created_at, updated_at

Now I want to add a flag for each object for name and id of the contacts like this

```
@contacts.each do |contact| 
  contact.add(name_flag) = true  if {my condition here}
end
```

and in the view I want to output the contacts depending on the flag as

```
 <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
    <%=  contact.['name'] if contact.[name_flag'] %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the flags?

Answer (score 0):

In controller:-

```
con = Contact.first(5)
@contacts = []
con.each do |contact| 
  if my_condition_here
   contact['name_flag'] = true
  end 
  @contacts << contact
end
```

In view:-

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
   <%=  contact.name if contact['name_flag']  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I did not ask for this. I have to add the flag to the array

Comment: For my project, I need to add the name_flag to the @contact object. How can I do that?

Comment: Try the updated post. Now name_flag is added to @contact object.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your condition isn't too complex, there's no problem with just putting that in your view really:

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <%= contact.name if {your condition here} %>
<% end %>
```

Edit:

If you want to move this condition into the model, you can simply define a method on your Contact model:

```
def name_flag
  {your condition here}
end
```

And then you can call this within your view:

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <%= contact.name if contact.name_flag %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For my project, I need to add the name_flag to the @contact object. How can I do that?